# Nginx ingress no longer working (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm running into an issue where our nginx-ingress is no longer working properly. We had an issue where one of the worker nodes went down and it ended up evicting a number of ingress pods. We created a new worker node and the pods were recreated with no errors.
The error I was getting was the following when I inspected the logs for the nginx-ingress pods:

```
W0731 18:11:20.640729       1 warnings.go:70] networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
E0731 18:11:26.533749       1 reflector.go:138] /home/runner/work/kubernetes-ingress/kubernetes-ingress/internal/k8s/controller.go:574: Failed to watch *v1.Policy: failed to list *v1.Policy: the server could not find the requested resource (get policies.k8s.nginx.org)
E0731 18:11:31.778992       1 reflector.go:138] /home/runner/work/kubernetes-ingress/kubernetes-ingress/internal/k8s/controller.go:571: Failed to watch *v1.VirtualServer: failed to list *v1.VirtualServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualservers.k8s.nginx.org)
E0731 18:11:51.190680       1 reflector.go:138] /home/runner/work/kubernetes-ingress/kubernetes-ingress/internal/k8s/controller.go:572: Failed to watch *v1.VirtualServerRoute: failed to list *v1.VirtualServerRoute: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualserverroutes.k8s.nginx.org)
E0731 18:11:59.259723       1 reflector.go:138] /home/runner/work/kubernetes-ingress/kubernetes-ingress/internal/k8s/controller.go:574: Failed to watch *v1.Policy: failed to list *v1.Policy: the server could not find the requested resource (get policies.k8s.nginx.org)
E0731 18:12:11.070691       1 reflector.go:138] /home/runner/work/kubernetes-ingress/kubernetes-ingress/internal/k8s/controller.go:573: Failed to watch *v1alpha1.TransportServer: failed to list *v1alpha1.TransportServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get transportservers.k8s.nginx.org)
E0731 18:12:26.943999       1 reflector.go:138] /home/runner/work/kubernetes-ingress/kubernetes-ingress/internal/k8s/controller.go:571: Failed to watch *v1.VirtualServer: failed to list *v1.VirtualServer: the server could not find the requested resource (get virtualservers.k8s.nginx.org)
```

Our current ingress looks something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "900"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "900"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "256k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers: "4 256k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: client_header_buffer_size 256k
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
    nginx.org/websocket-services: "contoso-service,sbase-service"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls2023
    hosts:
      - sbasedev.net
      - contosodev.net
  rules:
  - host: sbasedev.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: sbase-service
          servicePort: 80
```

For context, the kubernetes version we are running is v1.12.0. When I checked the nginx version inside the pods, the version running is 1.19.6.

I tried deleting and recreating the pods however the same error occured. This configuration was confirmed working until the nginx pods were evicted and recreated.

Answer (score 1):

Upon checking the error messages, It seems like your Ingress resources are using deprecated API version [networking.k8s.io/v1beta1](http://networking.k8s.io/v1beta1) which was deprecated in v 1.19 and the Ingress Controller is unable to find CRD’s that are needed. You should update your ingress resources to use the [networking.k8s.io/v1](http://networking.k8s.io/v1) API version and install the missing CRD’s. Here are documentations that can be helpful in your use case. [1][2][3]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

[3] https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I managed to resolve the issue with one of the worker nodes and get it back online again. It seems the issue was fixed if all the nginx pods were deployed across all nodes (since it is a daemonset). I am curious if the requirements for nginx is for all pods to be running and non to be evicted. Can the Nginx pods have one pod in the daemonset being down, or do they all need to be running?